# Syntax/concept of a non-iterated loop?

Tags: loops, conceptual, concept

I'm trying to iterate through a loop (any programming language, really, but for this exercise I happen to be using c#) and I was just wondering... what happens when you try to use a loop that doesn't iterate at all (i.e. ...."null"?)

For example:

```
int x = choose(0,1,2); 
for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
    //some stuff
}
```

Like, what would happen if x gets chosen to be `0`? Does it just become a useless for loop on that case? Will my program crash? Is that bad programming practice? etc. etc.

I'm mainly asking because I'm trying to format a concatenated string but only if some array has enough elements. thanks

Comment: Please do not deface your post, specially since someone has taken the time to answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simply put, nothing will happen. A `for` loop is like an `if` statement where it checks the condition and repeats while that condition is true.

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
```

This is saying:

1. Initialize `i` to 0
2. Check if `i` is less than the value of `x`
3. Increment `i` at the end of the loop

If `x` is 0, then the loop will simply not run; it becomes useless.